# Should I have "but" or not? and sentence structure suggestions

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I have a sentence:

> We would like to point out in XXX(a paper) a `same result of` YYY(YYY is
>   a statement) is done, with a different condition, `(but)`without using ZZZ
>   method.

My question:

1. I feel weird by using `a same result of YYY`. What I want to say is in XXX paper, a result YYY is also proved. Any suggestions?
2. I want to emphasize that in XXX paper, it proves YYY without using ZZZ. Can I use `but` to emphasize `without`? Or should I use `however` or something else?

Comment: Three things.  "Same" requires "the".  Results are obtained, not done. "However" is the same as "but".

Comment: I think that without the "but" it would be a simple statement, so if you do want to emphasize, "but" would provide that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use slightly different phrase structure:

> We would like to point out in `PaperXXX` that `ResultYYY` was achieved using different conditions, even without using `MethodZZZ`.